# How to effectively blur a single object in a scene with GLSL?

Tags: java, glsl, shader

I'm trying to blur an object in my scene with a GLSL shader.

What I do is when I'm drawing my scene, I may reach an object that needs to be blurred. When I do, I do so in two passes (from what I understand this is more optimized than doing so in a single pass).

So I draw the object to an off-screen FBO (transparent BG) with a horizontal blur. I then draw this FBO to the screen's default FBO with the vertical blur.

This is the result (**method #1** in this image):
[image]

The white "glow" is problematic. However, if I draw the object to an off-screen FBO that does **not** have a transparent BG, I get the correct blur result from **method #2** in the above image. However, I now obviously have a white BG behind the object - also not good.

What I'm asking is how exactly are you supposed to blur with the two-pass approach if you can't use a transparent-BG FBO? Or is there some trick I can do to fix this? Maybe mess with the blending src/dst functions?